# Unable to send the embeded message in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to send an announcement to the channel but I receive this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')
```

The script:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const clients = new Discord.Client({ intents: 14087});
const allow = require("./admin/announceAllow.json")
module.exports = {
    name: 'announce',
    description: "announce stuff to announcement server",
    execute(message, args, cmdName, extraString, status, reason,user,id, prefix,lang){
        if(cmdName == ""){
            let err = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("There was an error while announcing")
            .setDescription("Reason: `Empty string`")
            .setColor("RED")
            message.channel.send({embeds:[err]})
        }else
        if(!(cmdName == "")){
        var toAnnounce = cmdName.replace("announce ","")
        var toSend = "929580453554434089"
        var splitToAnnounce = toAnnounce.split(",,")
        console.log(`${splitToAnnounce[0].replace("|n", "\n")}\n${splitToAnnounce[1].replace("|n", "\n")}\n${splitToAnnounce[2].replace("|n", "\n")}`)
        if(allow[message.author.id + ""]){
            try{
                let announce = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle(`${splitToAnnounce[0].replace("|n", "\n")}`)
                .setDescription(`${splitToAnnounce[1].replace("|n", "\n")}`)
                .setColor(`${splitToAnnounce[2].replace("|n", "\n")}`)
                clients.channels.cache.get(`${toSend}`).send({embeds:[announce]})
            }catch(e){
                let err = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("There was an error while announcing")
                .setDescription("Possible reason: `Bot don't have permission, bot script outdated, bot error, user input error, color error`\n\nUsage: <prefix> announce `title,,content,,color`\ntip: use `|n` for new line\ncolor: `RED,BLUE,GREEN` etc")
                .setColor("RED")
                message.channel.send({embeds:[err]}) 
                console.log(e)   
            }
        }else
        if(!(allow[message.author.id + ""])){...........
```

Anyone, please explain why did this error occur and how to fix it

Comment: Wow you've got a lot of arguments... are they in the right order? Where exactly does this error occur?

Comment: mhm, yep they are the right one, I triple checked

Answer (score 0):

Have a check on the channel ID in `toSend`.
I have recreated a simply version of this code, and able to get the same error while the channel ID is inputed **wrongly**. If your command handler is working fine, the problem is mostly come up at the `clients.channels.cache.get...` part.
Above TypeError it should be showing you which line of code is being run as occuring the error.